# Why is video from canvas.captureStream empty when using drawImage with MediaRecorder

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-mediarecorder

I have a perfectly working demo animation within a canvas element that I can record as a webm video file with MediaRecorder and `captureStream()` from the `<canvas>` element.

The animations from the 2d context api come out just fine in the resulting video, but when I try to use `drawImage()` in order to add an image to the canvas I can't seem to make it work properly. In the latter case the `MediaRecorder.ondataavailable` handler doesn't receive valid data and the resulting video file is a 0-byte file.

I even implemented a demo where I can toggle whether or not a `drawImage()` call is performed. in the code below, if `drawImage = false` the video is generated without a problem, but if `drawImage` is toggled to `true`, it will generate a 0-byte file instead.

In order to demonstrate, I put together this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/keyboardsamurai/3tkm0dp6/16/

I am running this code on "Chrome Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-Bit)" on MacOS - not even sure if it is supposed to run on Firefox etc. since the MediaRecorder API throws seemingly unrelated errors on FF.

See also the full code here:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="drawing_canvas" width="1280" height="720"></canvas>

<script>
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = 'https://66.media.tumblr.com/84d332cafeb1052c477c979281e5713b/tumblr_owe3l0tkCj1wxdq3zo1_1280.jpg';

    window.requestAnimationFrame(animation);

    const drawImage = false;  // toggle to 'true' to make this example fail
    const canvas = document.getElementById('drawing_canvas');

    const allChunks = [];
    const recorder = initMediaRecorder(canvas);
    recorder.start();

    setTimeout(function (e) {
        console.log("Video ended");
        recorder.stop();
    }, 5000);

    function initMediaRecorder(canvasElement) {
        const stream = canvasElement.captureStream(60);
        const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {mimeType: 'video/webm'});
        recorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
            console.log("data handler called");
            if (e.data) {
                console.log("data available: " + e.data.size)
                if (e.data.size > 0) {
                    console.log("data added");
                    allChunks.push(e.data);
                }
            } else {
                console.error("Data handler received no data in event: " + JSON.stringify(e))
            }
        };

        recorder.onstop = function (e) {
            const fullBlob = new Blob(allChunks);
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.style.display = 'none';

            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(fullBlob);
            link.download = 'media.webm';

            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            link.remove();
        };
        return recorder;
    }


    function animation() {
        const now = new Date();
        const ctx = document.getElementById('drawing_canvas').getContext('2d');

        if (drawImage) {
            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        }

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 150, 150);

        ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.rect(0, 0, 1280, 720);
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.save();

        ctx.translate(75, 75);
        ctx.scale(0.4, 0.4);
        ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / 2);
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.lineWidth = 8;
        ctx.lineCap = 'round';

        // Hour marks
        ctx.save();
        for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 6);
            ctx.moveTo(100, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(120, 0);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        ctx.restore();

        // Minute marks
        ctx.save();
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        for (i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
            if (i % 5 != 0) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(117, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(120, 0);
                ctx.stroke();
            }
            ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 30);
        }
        ctx.restore();

        const sec = now.getSeconds();
        const min = now.getMinutes();
        let hr = now.getHours();
        hr = hr >= 12 ? hr - 12 : hr;

        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';

        // write Hours
        ctx.save();
        ctx.rotate(hr * (Math.PI / 6) + (Math.PI / 360) * min + (Math.PI / 21600) * sec);
        ctx.lineWidth = 14;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(-20, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(80, 0);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();

        // write Minutes
        ctx.save();
        ctx.rotate((Math.PI / 30) * min + (Math.PI / 1800) * sec);
        ctx.lineWidth = 10;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(-28, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(112, 0);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();

        // Write seconds
        ctx.save();
        ctx.rotate(sec * Math.PI / 30);
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#D40000';
        ctx.fillStyle = '#D40000';
        ctx.lineWidth = 6;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(-30, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(83, 0);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(0, 0, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(95, 0, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)';
        ctx.arc(0, 0, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = 14;
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#325FA2';
        ctx.arc(0, 0, 142, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.restore();

        window.requestAnimationFrame(animation);
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**: The above behavior is **confirmed to be replicable** on at least these Chrom(e/ium) versions:

Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-Bit) on MacOS Mojave 10.14.5

Version 77.0.3849.0 (Official Build) canary (64-Bit) on MacOS Mojave 10.14.5

Version 77.0.3770.100 (Official Build) snap (64-bit) on Ubuntu 19.04 Disco Dingo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That happens because your image is coming from a cross-domain resource and has tainted your canvas.
Tainting a canvas from which a MediaStream is being captured will stop said MediaStream from capturing any new image.

Also, trying to capture a MediaStream from such a tainted canvas will throw a SecurityError.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const stream = canvas.captureStream();
vid.srcObject = stream;

const img = new Image();
img.onload = e => {
  console.log('will taint the canvas')
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  // and if we try now to capture a new stream, we have a clear error
  const stream2 = canvas.captureStream();
}
img.src = "https://66.media.tumblr.com/84d332cafeb1052c477c979281e5713b/tumblr_owe3l0tkCj1wxdq3zo1_1280.jpg";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,20,20);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<video id="vid" controls autoplay muted></video>
```

To circumvent it, you need the server to send the image in a cross-origin compliant way, by setting correctly the Access-control-origin headers to accept your own domain, then requesting this image with the `crossorigin` attribute. The server from which you are loading this particular image does allow anyone to access their data in such a cross-origin compliant way, so we can demonstrate the front-end part:

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const stream = canvas.captureStream();
vid.srcObject = stream;

const img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'; // add this to request the image as cross-origin allowed
img.onload = e => {
  console.log('will not taint the canvas anymore')
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  // and if we try now to capture a new stream, we have a clear error
  const stream2 = canvas.captureStream();
}
img.src = "https://66.media.tumblr.com/84d332cafeb1052c477c979281e5713b/tumblr_owe3l0tkCj1wxdq3zo1_1280.jpg";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,20,20);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<video id="vid" controls autoplay muted></video>
```